# Yours or you... which pronoun should be used here?

Tags: pronouns

"Happiness is.. Having friends with the same mental disorders as yours."

I was just wondering if this sentace is grammatical or should it be "you" at the end?

Either way; it's very funny!

Thanks

[image]

Comment: ...they're both fine. The possessive form is "reduced" from ***your disorders = yours***. The simple pronoun is reduced from *...the same mental disorders as / that **you have***.

Comment: Consider also *Happiness is.. Having friends with **worse** mental disorders **than you / yours***. In which context [“…than I am” vs. “…than me”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/) and [“than I” vs. “than me”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43683/) should be helpful.