# Adverb clause of comparision

Tags: pronouns, adverbial-phrases, personal-pronouns, comparative-degree

example1:  “He is wiser that I”
 example2: “He is wiser than me”. I know example1 is correct and example2 is grammatically wrong. But please check the below conditions

> Sentence1:  “I found her smarter than him”
>
> Sentence2: “I found her smarter than he”

I found that sentence1 is correct, but not sentence2, unlike above examples which are of same model. which sentence is correct? What is the difference between the meaning of these two sentences?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“...than I am” vs. “...than me”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/than-i-am-vs-than-me)

Comment: (Personally, I think you've been badly taught. Your example #2 is by far the most idiomatically natural choice today, and anyone who still thinks only version #1 is "correct" is just pedantically sticking to outmoded Victorian "standards".)

Comment: Sentence 2. is not wrong -- it's fine. Sentence 1. is possible but very formal. They have the same meaning, but the syntax is different. In 1. "him" is object of  the prep "than", while in 2. "he" is subject of a reduced clause, cf the unreduced clause "I found her smarter than I am".

Comment: Sentence two suffers from an ambiguity. Does it mean "I found her smarter than he found her" or "I found her smarter than he is smart"?