# Grammar Using I

Tags: phrase-choice

I’m trying to find out which of the two are correct…”Turns out she’s crazier than me.” Or “Turns out she’s crazier than I.”
I know it may seem silly to many people but I’m curious which is the proper way to say the statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“...than I am” vs. “...than me”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/than-i-am-vs-than-me)

Comment: Both are possible. The difference is one of formality, with "I" being more formal than "me".

Comment: @Joachim No, that question isn't equivalent to this one because as the question itself makes clear in that one, you could parse the sentence as having the transitive verb "ask" elided, in which case the accusative pronoun form could apply, which would even follow *prescriptivist* grammar rules. However, in this case, with no possible elided transitive verb, there's no way to parse it as following prescriptive rules, so this is a question only about *descriptivist* rules.

Answer (score 1):

While both forms are possible, the usual and unmarked form is "crazier than me".  The use of "...than I" is notably formal.

Trying to analyse the case of a pronoun when no verb is present, by pretending that the verb is present seems to be a very unsatisfactory way of understanding grammar.

There is no verb, and the default form of the first person pronoun is "me" when not governing a verb.

In formal speech, and consistent with Latin grammar, the form "than I" would also be correct.  However this context uses informal language "Turns out..."  and the description of a person as "crazy" are both informal.  In this informal context "... than I" would be jarring and not idiomatic.

Comment: The idea with nominative "I" is that it appears as in unreduced clauses: "Turns out she’s crazier than I am". Informal style has "me" where the missing verb cannot be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a source of confusion for many native speakers.

Use "I" when it is the subject. Use "me" when it is the object. Simple examples: "I gave the box to Bob." I am doing the giving; Bob is receiving. "Bob gave the box to me." Bob is doing the giving; I am receiving.

Also use "me" when it is the object of a preposition. "The sky is over me." "Over" is a preposition. Therefore I use "me" and not "I".

In this case, "than" is a preposition. So it should be "crazier than me", not "crazier than I".

The same rule applies even when there's a complex object. Like you should write, "Bob gave the box to Sally and me", not "... to Sally and I."

Comment: Why not "... crazier than I [am]."?

Comment: If the pronoun is understood as subject of the comparative clause, as is the case here, then both forms are possible. The difference is one of style, with "I" being more formal than "me"

Comment: "... than I am" is correct.  But the example doesn't contain a verb "am".  The question is not about the correct form of the pronoun when the there is clause "I am" but when there is just a single pronoun  "than me".

Comment: @JamesK Yes. Not to be defensive, but if you say, "If it was a different question than your answer would be wrong" doesn't address whether the answer is correct for the question asked. :-) Yes, "... crazier than I am" would also be a grammatically correct sentence. ("... crazier than me am" would be incorrect.)